# How to target every first two or three elements alternatively in javascript loop

Tags: javascript

I am able to target only first 2 elements with change in background color. Like, first 2 elements background to red, and next 2 elements leaving as it is. And background red to 4th and 5th element..so on. I want to target every 2 elements alternatively. How can i change a variable value dynamically which can be easy everytime like if var count = 2; every first 2 elements red...if count = 4; every first 4 elements to red and next 4 to gray....Actually I wanted to use styling with dynamic value like `element[i].clientWidth` etc to elements. I just used background color for this example so that i can change it later according to my styling if once it works.

```
 <style>
        ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    <style>
 <ul id="pix" class="select">
            <li class="">one</li>
            <li class="">two</li>
            <li class="">three</li>
            <li class="">four</li>
            <li class="">five</li>
            <li class="">six</li>
            <li class="">seven</li>
            <li class="">eight</li>
            <li class="">nine</li>
            <li class="">ten</li>
        </ul>

    <script>
    var pix = document.getElementById("pix");
        var piximgs = pix.children;

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < piximgs.length; i++) {
            piximgs[i].style.background = "gray";
            //   if (i && (i % 2 == 0)) {

                    piximgs[i % 2].style.background = "red";
            //  }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: you should use css instead and :nth-child property

Comment: i.e. :nth-child(2n) and.or :nth-child(2n+1)

Comment: You could add a class to odd numbers and another one for even numbers, that way you can easily reference either of them

Comment: @Satif I wanted to use styling with dynamic value like clientWidth + "px" to every first 2 or 3 elements and leave next 2 or 3 elements without styling in a loop. This cant be done i using nth-child(2n) in css. I just used background color for an example so that i can change it later according to my styling if once it works. So i need this in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified solution with a variable `count`:

```html
<style>
  ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
</style>

<ul id="pix" class="select">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
</ul>

<script>
  var count = 3;
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#pix li"))
  .forEach((li,i)=>
    li.style.backgroundColor=Math.floor(i/count)%2?"red":"gray");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a flag - `next` - which you toggle whenever there is a match for the mod division, so that you track that the next element should also be red.

```html
<style>
  ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
</style>

<ul id="pix" class="select">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
</ul>

<script>
  var pix = document.getElementById("pix");
  var piximgs = pix.children;

  var i;
  var next = false;
  for (i = 0; i < piximgs.length; i++) {
    if(next) {
      piximgs[i].style.background = "red";
      next = false;
    }
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      piximgs[i].style.background = "red";
      next = true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i need little more help. I wanted to change the value dynamically, Right now it works for 2 elements. What if i need 3 elements red and next 3 gray and again next  3 red.....Can i change a variable value dynamically which can be easy everytime like if var count = 2; every first 2 elements red...if count = 4; every 4 elements to red and next 4 to gray....Actually I wanted to use styling with dynamic value like piximgs[i].clientWidth etc to elements. I just used background color for an example so that i can change it later according to my styling if once it works.